Recover iPhone clipboard after Mac replaced it
I cut text into my iPhone clipboard to paste into something that took a bit to load, and did a small thing on my Mac while waiting, which involved copy-pasting on the mac, then tried to paste on the iPhone and found that the block of important text copied on the iPhone had been replaced by whatever trivial thing have been copied on the Mac
How can I recover the iPhone's clipboard content?

I'm going to say "you can't". The clipboard is temporary: there is no log or record of what was there.
In the future, you’ll need to paste immediately into notes or another fast to respond place such as Apple’s Quick Note feature.
